# Have I made $k$ the subject of this equation correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equation is:
$10k = \frac{7k}{3t} + 12t$

Multiply by $3t$:

$30kt = 7k+36t^2$

Subtract by $7k$:

$(36t-7)k = \frac{36t^2}{30t}$

Divide by $(360t-7)$:

$k = \frac{36t^2}{30t-7} $

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the 7k, I'm gonna have another try. Its proper stumped me with k been at both sides

Comment: Hiya moo, i've edited my post with what i think is the correct answer. Does it now look right ?

Comment: I see i've put 360t instead of 36t. I cant figure out anything else I've done wrong.